# Possible to convert UIButton control events to UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a situation where I have to work around a bug in iOS7 and need to convert the `UIButton` control events:

`UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`
`UIControlEventTouchDown` 
`UIControlEventTouchUpInside` 
`UIControlEventTouchDragOutside` 
`UIControlEventTouchDragInside` 
`UIControlEventTouchDragInside`

to `UIGestureRecgonizer` (I can't use `UIView` touch methods such as `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`, etc. either). I'm kind of interested if this is even possible anyway.

For instance, I'm thinking of a way to convert `UIControlEventTouchDown` and can't think of a way. `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` both would not work.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer for a SpriteKit game to implement line segment intersection, pretty sure it would be easily adaptable for mimicking a UIButton too. Keep track of the previous location of your gesture recognizer, I just used a static CGPoint that I updated every time my selector fired. Then, just check the previous position and the current position with CGRectContainsPoint using your button's frame, and depending on those results, do whatever you need to do. If both are inside the frame, that's the same as UIControlEventDragInside, if both are outside, that's UIControlEventDragOutside, if the previous is outside and the current is inside, that's UIControlEventDragEnter, etc etc. Also make sure to check the gesture recognizer's state so you know when to call TouchUpInside/Outside. I'd make sure to have a damn good reason to do this, but it seems workable to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGestureRecognizer
{
    if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

        CGPoint touchedPoint = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView: self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchedPoint))
        {
            [self addHighlights];
        }
        else
        {
            [self removeHighlights];
        }
    }
    else if (longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (self.highlightView.superview)
        {
            [self removeHighlights];
        }

        CGPoint touchedPoint = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView: self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchedPoint))
        {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonViewDidTouchUpInside:)])
            {
                [self.delegate buttonViewDidTouchUpInside:self];
            }
        }
    }
}
```